# How to make image not to take the new style settings, after drag function. jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that sends images back and forth between the two div elements by double clicking on the image . You should then be able to drag pictures freely in the second div element. Then you can double- click the image again to send the image back to its origin div elements. Here the problem arises . When I send back the image it assumes a different style position . How do I get the picture to get its old style position?

Comment: as I understood .. you can set attribute  data-index="imageindex" for every image .. and just read that data-index while you want to return it back ..

Comment: what is `style position`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I got what you mean.

After you drag your image around the `#dropbox`, jQuery adds an inline style to it to preserve its position after you drop it. Something like `style="position: relative; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: 73px; top: 52px;"`. So when you doubleclick, the image is moved to `#imagebox` still having these positioning styles.

To prevent this, you can just reset these style props in your doubleclick handler like so:

```
$(e).css({ "top": "auto", "bottom": "auto", "left": "auto", "right": "auto" });
```

Here's the demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/t8rL4s2f/)

Comment: Thanks! I discovered a new problem when I ran the code . I have certain measure of my dropbox. When I 'm using a lot of images they come outside my #dropbox. 

I cant use min-height & min-width on that div (#dropbox). Is there a way to make the images come on top of each other at the end when there is no space inside the #dropbox anymore.

I used your demo to show the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/t8rL4s2f/1/

Comment: Yes, you can adjust ```z-index``` and offset of an image inside the ```#dropbox``` when it's overflowing. I updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to detach if you're also using appendTo. DOM nodes can only have one parent, so moving them to a new parent necessarily also removes their old one (so they can't exist in two places at once)

As for the image position, your [`appendTo`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo) call *appends* an image to its new parent, so it'll always end up being the last element in the child set. If you don't want that, then you should not use `appendTo`, but use code that inserts the image in its original position, whatever that was before you sent it over (so remember to record the image position somewhere if you care about preserving it)